# ES7 - How to stop(cut) async/await chaining

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

If I use async/await function in a nested function call, I think the callers of that async/await functions should have async/await prefix.

For example, in this situation:

```
function a() {
  b();
}
function b() {
  c();
}
function c() {
  d();
}

...

function y() {
  z();
}
```

If `z` was async function, those functions should be:

```
async function a() {
  await b();
}
async function b() {
  await c();
}
async function c() {
  await d();
}

...

async function y() {
  await z();
}
```

When/How is it appropriate to stop the chaining of async/await?

Comment: @guijob `await` have to be in `async` function, haven't it?

Answer (score 2):

`async` function is just syntactic sugar for promises. It's a function that returns a promise and should be treated like one.

At some point there should have either:

```
a().catch(...)
```

Or `async` IIFE:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    await a();
  } catch (e) { ... }
})();
```